# Android: Is it possible to create a log out function without an online database?

Tags: android, logging, out

I was able to create a simple working login module without a database with the help of some of the folks here thanks again . The correct login inputs are declared.
So is it possible to add a functioning log off button to this? As in the user can't go back with the "back button"?

my project was based from this link

http://androidcodeexample.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-login.html

thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, just negate/destroy whatever value/credential indicates that they are logged in, and check it in onResume() of every Activity which should only work when logged in.  If you find they are actually logged out, use an Intent to send them to the login Activity.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, in the second activity to make the users unable to go back to the login screen you use this code in the second activity overriding the back button functionality

```
@override
public void onBackPressed() 
{

}
```

And to go back to the log in screen, you can use the following code inside the function that delegates the button's click:

```
private void onClickLogOutButton()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogInActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish(); 
}
```

The this.finish() will close the instance of the activity of the second screen, this will avoid the users to go back to the second activity pressing the back button.